# Attribute based filtering using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to filter using a date range based on data attributes and it's not working. I can get the text based filtering to work but not the date range.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="notificationCard" data-details="Change"
     data-filter-wftype="GVChangeReview"
     data-filter-statusdate="6/21/2020" style="display: block;">
    Some stuff
</div>
<div class="notificationCard" data-details="Review"
     data-filter-wftype="GVChangeReview"
     data-filter-statusdate="7/21/2020" style="display: block;">
    Some stuff
</div>
<div class="notificationCard" data-details="Review"
     data-filter-wftype="GVChangeReview"
     data-filter-statusdate="9/10/2020" style="display: block;">
    Some stuff
</div>
```

And JavaScript code is

```
var $notificationCards = $('.notificationCard');
$notificationCards.filter("[data-filter-statusdate='5/20/2020'],[data-filter-statusdate='7/22/2020']").show();
```

I was hoping to have only first two div's show up but none of them is showing up. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a9z2xkm/)

Comment: your dates in filtering and the HTML do not match up. Can you clarify your expected output ?

Comment: You can not use filter (with strings) to filter on the given range. You would have to use a filter function and parse the value of the filter-statusdate to a date and then do some comparison. See "Using a Filter Function" on the jQuery documentation page: https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use attribute selectors in this way, as they can only match specific values. You can instead create `Date`s from the start and end strings and loop over all of the `div`s, hiding it if the date is less than the start of greater than the end, i.e. not in the range.

```js
function filter()
{
 var $notificationCards = $('.notificationCard');
 let start = new Date('5/20/2020'), end = new Date('7/22/2020');
 $notificationCards.each(function(){
  let date = new Date($(this).data('filter-statusdate'));
  if(date < start || date > end){
    $(this).hide();
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notificationCard" data-details="Change"
     data-filter-wftype="GVChangeReview"
     data-filter-statusdate="6/21/2020" style="display: block;">
    Some stuff (6/21/2020)
</div>
<div class="notificationCard" data-details="Review"
     data-filter-wftype="GVChangeReview"
     data-filter-statusdate="7/21/2020" style="display: block;">
    Some stuff (7/21/2020)
</div>
<div class="notificationCard" data-details="Review"
     data-filter-wftype="GVChangeReview"
     data-filter-statusdate="9/10/2020" style="display: block;">
    Some stuff (9/10/2020)
</div>

<button onclick=filter()>Filter between 5/20/2020 and 7/22/2020</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @SP1 No problem.